# Why do I get a segmentation fault when attempting to execute an instruction writing to memory when the debugger can manually write to the same memory?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, gdb, x86-64, exploit

This is for x86-64, part of some stack overflow exploit.

gdb output:

```
=> 0x000055555555e996:  48 89 18    mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rbx
```

Move rbx into the address of memory stored at rax, simple. Since it segfaults at this instruction, let's look at it.

What is at rax?

```
(gdb) i r rax
rax            0x7ffff79f4c80      140737347800192
```

Is this memory valid?

```
(gdb) x/16b $rax
0x7ffff79f4c80 <_itoa_upper_digits>:    0x30    0x31    0x32    0x33    0x34    0x35    0x36    0x37
0x7ffff79f4c88 <_itoa_upper_digits+8>:  0x38    0x39    0x41    0x42    0x43    0x44    0x45    0x46
```

Well, at least I can read. Can I write?

```
(gdb) set $rbx = 0x4141414141414141
(gdb) set {unsigned long} $rax = $rbx
(gdb) x/16b $rax
0x7ffff79f4c80 <_itoa_upper_digits>:    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x7ffff79f4c88 <_itoa_upper_digits+8>:  0x38    0x39    0x41    0x42    0x43    0x44    0x45    0x46
```

Seems to work fine, and this set operation does indeed seem to actually write to memory, attempting the same to a known invalid address will result in an error. So it seems I can both write and read to this memory.

Let's try to execute this instruction then. Still the same one:

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x55555555e996:  mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rbx
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(a=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x376141366141355d>)
    at test.c:371
371     asm volatile("mov %rbx,(%rax);"
=> 0x000055555555e996:  48 89 18    mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rbx
   0x000055555555e999:  c3  ret
```

Why does it fail when I've just verified I can write there?

Comment: Are you trying to write to a executable region? It's most likely write-protected, GDB knows about this and unprotects it before writing.

Comment: Hm, that might be, I'm a bit thrown off by the "Cannot access memory at address 0x376141366141355d", that address makes little sense to me.

Comment: Is it possible to examine memory read/write/exec attributes at an arbitrary memory location outside of the defined memory regions? If I have to define it then it seems I have to set the memory attributes manually ...

Comment: `pmap -x <process id>` shows you all memory regions and their access attributes. Not sure if there is a command in GDB for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it fail when I've just verified I can write there?

The program *can't* write there, only GDB can.

The address you are trying to write to is in the `.text` section, which is normally `mmap`ed with `PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC` and *without* `PROT_WRITE`.

However, GDB (or any process that is `ptrace`ing this one), is allowed to write to such mappings. That is necessary for GDB to be able to insert breakpoints (which often requires re-writing program instructions).

Comment: Thanks, should have realized that since it is listing the address as being part of the itoa function ... however, what is up with this address 0x376141366141355d?

Comment: @AlphaCentauri: `0x376141366141355d` is not a valid address.  It's non-canonical (upper 16 bits aren't the same as bit 48, i.e. it's not a 48-bit number sign-extended to 64) so there's absolutely no way for that virtual address to be mapped to anything.  Looks like you loaded ASCII data and tried to use it as a pointer.  Maybe you overwrote a pointer in memory with something.